# What is the issue with this CTE WITH clause in PL SQL /Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, common-table-expression

I have below query.
The below query WITH CTE, it is returning 4 Records.

As I gave the comments, the below Select query has 55 Records and with And clause it should remove those 4 Records and return 51 records. Instead it is returning simply those 4 records only.

Just for testing I commented that AND clause and then it is functioning as expected and returning 55+4 = total of 59 Records.

How to fix this WITH CTE. What is wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CUSTCONNECT.sp_GetPodConfigurationGridData( 
p_podURL            IN varchar2,  --PodUrl
p_serverType        IN varchar2,
p_serverName        IN varchar2,
p_publishedDate     IN date,
P_RECORDSET         OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN P_RECORDSET FOR

--This has total of 4 Records
WITH PodServerRecords(Key, value, Overwrite, ServerName, ServerType, PublishDate ) AS (    
 select
         PC.KeyId as Key, KeyIdValue as value, 'Pod' as Overwrite, ''  as ServerName,  '' as Servertype, PC.PublishDate 
    from (select 
            Keylog.*, row_number() over (partition by Keylog.KeyId order by Keylog.PublishDate desc) as RowNu
          from PodConfigLog_Tab Keylog
          where Keylog.URL = p_podURL 
          and Keylog.PublishDate >= p_publishedDate and Keylog.PublishDate <= sysdate 
          ) PC 
    where PC.RowNu = 1 and PC.IsActive = 'T'
    UNION
    select 
        PCBS.KeyId as Key, KeyIdValue as value, 'Server' as Overwrite,  PCBS.ServerName, Servertype, PCBS.PublishDate
    from (select 
            Serlog.*, PS.ServerType, row_number() over (partition by Serlog.KeyId order by Serlog.PublishDate desc) as RowNu
          from PodConfigByServerLog_Tab Serlog 
          join PodServer_tab PS on PS.ServerName = Serlog.ServerName 
          and Serlog.URL = PS.URL
          where Serlog.URL = p_podURL 
          and Serlog.ServerName = p_serverName 
          and Serlog.PublishDate >= p_publishedDate and Serlog.PublishDate <= sysdate 
          ) PCBS 
    where PCBS.RowNu = 1 and PCBS.IsActive = 'T'

)

    --This has total of 55 Records 
    select
        PCK.KeyId as Key ,DefaultKeyIdValue as value,'Default' as Overwrite, '' as ServerName,  '' as Servertype, PCK.PublishDate
    from 
        (select 
            Keylog.*, row_number() over (partition by Keylog.KeyId order by Keylog.PublishDate desc) as RowNu
          from PodConfigKeyLog_Tab Keylog
          where Keylog.PublishDate >= p_publishedDate and Keylog.PublishDate <= sysdate 
          ) PCK
    join POD_TAB PS on PS.URL = p_podURL
    where PCK.RowNu = 1 and PCK.IsActive = 'T'
    --This And caluse should remove those 4 Records and total Records should be 51. 
    and PCK.KeyId not in (
        select KeyId
        from PodServerRecords 
    )
    UNION
    --This is total of 4 Records
    SELECT 
        Key, value, Overwrite, ServerName, ServerType, PublishDate
    FROM PodServerRecords 
    Order By Key;

END;
/
```

Comment: It's hard to find similarities between the different queries you provide. Why should they return the same numbers?

Comment: I think you should remove that `UNION` part of your query cause it's readding those 4 records from `PodServerRecords`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the CTE does not have a column called `KeyId`.  You renamed it to `Key`.  However, `NOT IN` has unexpected behavior when there are `NULL` values.  You can fix this by eliminating them directly:

```
PCK.KeyId not in (
        select psr.KeyId
        from PodServerRecords psr
        where psr.KeyId IS NOT NULL 
    )
```

I recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
NOT EXISTS (select 1
            from PodServerRecords psr
            where psr.KeyId = PCK.KeyId
           )
```

This may fix your problem.

Actually, I don't see a `KeyId` in your CTE.  So, I think you want:

```
NOT EXISTS (select 1
            from PodServerRecords psr
            where psr.Key = PCK.KeyId
           )
```

Note the preceding statements will return errors, indicating that the problem is the misnamed column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove that `UNION` part of your query cause it's readding those 4 records from `PodServerRecords`. Your query should rather be

```
 --This has total of 55 Records 

    select
        PCK.KeyId as Key ,DefaultKeyIdValue as value,'Default' as Overwrite, '' as ServerName,  '' as Servertype, PCK.PublishDate
    from 
        (select 
            Keylog.*, row_number() over (partition by Keylog.KeyId order by Keylog.PublishDate desc) as RowNu
          from PodConfigKeyLog_Tab Keylog
          where Keylog.PublishDate >= p_publishedDate and Keylog.PublishDate <= sysdate 
          ) PCK
    join POD_TAB PS on PS.URL = p_podURL
    where PCK.RowNu = 1 and PCK.IsActive = 'T'
    --This And caluse should remove those 4 Records and total Records should be 51. 
    and PCK.KeyId not in (
        select KeyId
        from PodServerRecords 
    );
```